# Getting practicality of PHP from Ruby or Python

Tags: php, python, ruby

I have a rather odd problem. I love the practicality of PHP - specifically that I can fairly safely assume that on any random server I'll have access to the MySQL libraries, and that I can go between PHP/HTML with `<?` and `?>`. That said, I find the language atrocious - Ruby and Python are considerably more expressive, yet since they're not web-specific, they lack both of those features - at least last I used them both.

So my question is, is there some way to get the practicality of PHP from Ruby or Python (specifically the two issues I mentioned)? If not, is there some other language that doesn't feel like a C/C++ parser gone wrong?

Comment: I hear people throw the 'expressive' word around a ton when talking about Python or Ruby, but I've never been able to find more 'expessiveness' in those languages in comparison to Perl, or PHP, or JavaScript. Can someone give me an example of 'expressiveness' where Python or Ruby is, but PHP isn't?

Comment: Rails would give you all this and a bit more for Ruby and I think the same holds for Python with Django.

Comment: Look at [embedded ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ERuby), though realize you don't want to write the entire application in .rhtml

Comment: I've done Rails before; I don't like its forced approach to architecture.

Comment: @JonathanRich There are plenty of examples of linguistic expressiveness - here's just one in Python:

`posts = getPostsForListOfPostIDs([postkey.hex for postkey in timed_posts.keys()], 3)`

There's probably some way to do this with `array_walk` and an extra function - just nothing that looks nearly as nice (or is as readable).

Comment: While I'll agree that that looks nice, I think arguments about its readability are completely subjective.

Comment: @Melllvar PHP is pretty close - without knowing what that outer function is, nor what `postkey` is: `posts = getPostsForListOfPostIDs(array_map(function(postkey) { return postkey.hex; }, array_keys(timed_posts)), 3)`

Comment: Granted, it looks kinda like you just typed in something semi-random - why is there an object as the _key_ of the dict?

Comment: @Izkata this was just a random example. I'm sure there are others that are more applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like [Python Server Pages](http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/pyapi-psp.html)?

```
<html>
<%
  import time
%>
Hello world, the time is: <%=time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S")%>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like psp and eruby are the best alternatives; thanks

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're dealing with a large legacy codebase, it's relatively easy to avoid PHP's warts. Most hosts will have PHP 5.3 and, except for a few of the gems from 5.4, you're going to get a lot of functionality.

What specifically about PHP is it that you are trying to avoid?

Comment: As a scripting language, I find PHP not as expressive as either Ruby or Python. I realize this is rather subjective, and my goal here isn't to start an ideology war, but that's basically it. PHP got features like OO and lambdas way too late to make the language more elegant, and what it is today is something that looks like C (mind you, I have no problems with C itself), with random features that look out of place.

Comment: If you're looking for an elegant language, then PHP is not it. There is no other language that is ubiquitous as PHP, though.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to find out :)